# Calculation of Internet Checksum of two 16-bit streams

Tags: checksum

I want to calculate Internet checksum of two bit streams of 16 bits each. Do I need to break these strings into segments or I can directly sum the both?

Here are the strings:

```
String 1 = 1010001101011111
String 2 = 1100011010000110
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

No. You don't need to split them.

**Somewhat longer answer**

Not sure exactly what you mean by "*internet*" checksum (a hash or checksum is just the result of a mathematical operation, and has no direct relation or dependence on the internet), but anyway:

The checksum of any value should not depend on the length of the input. In theory, your input strings could be of any length at all.

You can test this with a basic online checksum generator [such as this one, for instance](https://defuse.ca/checksums.htm#checksums). That appears to generate a whole slew of checksums using lots of different algorithms. The names of the algorithms appear on the left in the list.

If you want to do this in code, a good starting point might be to search for examples using one of them in whatever language / environment you are working in.

Comment: Thank you very much